# Android OpenGL slow with sound

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm making game in **OpenGL 2.0** and I have big problems with sounds. I tried to play sounds with **SoundPool** and **MediaPlayer**, but always there is same problem.

When I play sounds,my fps is constant but sometimes sprites movement is slower,but fps same.

Comment: Ok, and what is your question? What have you done in terms of profiling your app?

Comment: How to solve this problem? How to do profilling?

Comment: Hard to say, try native decoder of audio.

Comment: What is native decoder of audio?

Comment: first of all post ur **code**